# Cannot boot into OS yureka

Tags: micromax-yu-yureka

After flashing philz recovery through fastboot mode.Yureka doesn't neither boot into OS nor into recovery.(But battery less than 10%)
When turned on shows boot image and then a blank screen.If charger is connected,shows battery status  when phone is off.
Downloaded philz from[Philz](http://www.androiddevs.net/Downloads/)
And executed fastboot -i 0x1ebf flash recovery philz.img

Comment: 1) Was the fastboot flashing recovery result successful? 2) Can you boot into fastboot mode now? 3) If yes, did you try any other recovery to flash? What are your results?

Comment: Yes fastboot flash was successfull.I can now boot into fastboot mode.Tried to flash stock recovery again

Comment: try twrp 3.0.2 from its original website and its 64 bit version.